# HTML Input Required not working as expected

Tags: html

This is supposed to be the template for a sign-up page that I am currently working on. I am having trouble with `<input required>` not being validated when the user submits the form - I would expect it to tell me that I have to fill out certain fields in order to submit / proceed, but this does not seem to be the case

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form method="post">
    <label for="f_name">First Name:</label>
    <input id="f_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_n" required>
    <label for="l_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input id="l_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_n" required>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label for="m_f_o">Male</label>
    <input id="m_f_o" type="radio" name="gender">
    <label for="f_m_o">Female</label>
    <input id="f_m_o" type="radio" name="gender">
    <label for="o_m_f">Other</label>
    <input id="o_m_f" type="radio" name="gender">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="your email" name="email" required>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" pattern=".{5,10}" required>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label>Birthday</label>
    <select name="month" required>
        <option value="Month">Month</option>
        <option value="jan">Jan</option>
        <option value="feb">Feb</option>
        <option value="mar">Mar</option>
        <option value="april">April</option>
        <option value="may">May</option>
        <option value="june">June</option>
        <option value="july">July</option>
        <option value="aug">Aug</option>
        <option value="sept">Sept</option>
        <option value="oct">Oct</option>
        <option value="nov">Nov</option>
        <option value="dec">Dec</option>
    </select>
        <select name="day" required>
        <option value="day">Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select name="year" required>
        <option value="year">Year</option>
        <option value="1990">1999</option>
        <option value="1991">1991</option>
        <option value="1992">1992</option>
        <option value="1993">1993</option>
        <option value="1994">1994</option>
        <option value="1995">1995</option>
        <option value="1996">1996</option>
        <option value="1997">1997</option>
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010">2010</option>
        <option value="2011">2011</option>
        <option value="2012">2012</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label>I agree to the</label>
    <a href="http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/terms-and-conditions">terms and conditions</a>
    <input type="checkbox" required>
</form>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the response/output that you expect? What is the response/error that you get? What have you tried changing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

- First, ensure that your inputs are closed.
- Secondly, you have multiple forms, one for each collection of inputs. You need a single form and the submit button needs to be included inside it.

Here's an example:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="f_name">First Name:</label>
    <input id="f_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_n" required />
    <label for="m_f_o">Male</label>
    <input id="m_f_o" type="radio" name="gender" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: the input tag is self-closing so I don't need to add a / but thanks for the effort

Comment: Huh, TIL. At any rate, the submit being part of a separate form is the reason your validation isn't firing.

Comment: that is true but how do you make them on separate lines

Comment: `<br>` to insert a line break